# Query within a for each loop? Trying to get user name for each foreign ID number in each row returned

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to display the user name of the person who liked another user's post for each record. I can only figure out how to display that user ID number so far though (which we get from points.LID). This is what code below does. I have tried a few things, but I can't figure out how to get a second sql query inside of the foreach loop so that I can get the user_name for the LID/ID for each liking user.

I need to get the user display name from LID sql somewhere/somehow so I can echo name of person who liked the post (the LID). I need use LID to connect to wp_users.ID in wp_users table and then grab wp_users.display_name. But can I insert such a query inside the foreach loop below?

I think I need to add something like (select points.LID from points where points.ID = $user_ID) Then get display name where wp_users.ID = points.LID

These are the 3 tables with the relevant columns:
1. points (ID, LID, SID), 
2. stories (ID, story_name)
3. wp_users (ID, display_name)

//THIS CODE RETURNS name of story and the ID NUMBER of the person who liked it (LID). But I need it to return the user name of the person who liked it (wp_users.display_name)

```
//only need current user for ID of author
$user_ID = get_current_user_id()

$results = $dbh->prepare("select 
stories.ID,
stories.SID,
stories.story_name,
points.ID,
points.LID,
points.PID,
wp_users.ID,
wp_users.display_name
FROM stories
JOIN points ON stories.SID=points.SID
JOIN wp_users ON stories.ID=wp_users.ID
where (stories.ID = $user_ID) and (PID = 1)");
$results->execute();

$row = $results->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

if ($row) {
echo '<table>';
echo '<tr>';
echo '<td><b>Name</b></td>';
echo '<td><b>Author</b></td>';
echo '</tr>';
foreach ($row as $all) {

//Get user display name from LID sql here? So I can echo name of person
//who liked the post (the LID) below? I need use LID to connect to
//wp_users.ID in wp_users table and then grab wp_users.display_name

$stp = stripslashes($all['story_name']);
echo '<tr>';
echo "<td><a href=\"http://example.com/complete-text?
writing=$all[SID]\">$stp</a></td>";
echo "<td><a href=\"http://example.com/portfolio?ID=$all[LID]\">
$all['LID']</a></td>";
}
echo '</table>';
}
?>
```

Comment: Have you tried using `$all['display_name']` instead of `$all['LID']`?

Comment: Yes, but that give display name for the ID of the author (stories.ID) and not the person who liked the story (LID)

Comment: Then you're going to have to add more information to the question. How do you know who liked the story? What is the table structure?

Comment: table structure is mentioned above in the original question/post. the points table has a LID column. That's the person who liked the story. But that person's user name is in wp_users.display_name

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SELECT 
  stories.ID,
  stories.SID,
  stories.story_name,
  points.ID,
  points.LID,
  points.PID,
  wp_users.ID,
  wp_users.display_name,
  wp_users2.display_name AS 'user_who_liked',
FROM
  stories 
  JOIN points 
    ON stories.SID = points.SID 
  JOIN wp_users 
    ON stories.ID = wp_users.ID 
  LEFT JOIN wp_users AS wp_users2 
    ON points.LID = wp_users2.ID 
WHERE (stories.ID = $user_ID) 
  AND (PID = 1) ;
```

Comment: sorry for inserting that sql to snippet, my answer keep rejected due to incorrect format

Comment: Thanks, but I didn't work. I think the approach is that I need two more sql statements, although I don't know how to integrate them: A:
(select points.LID from points where points.ID = $user_ID)

B:
Then get display name where wp_users.ID = points.LID

Comment: are you sure you change the `(stories.ID = 1) ` into `(stories.ID = $user_ID)` like you original query ?

Comment: yes i did. So that gets the current user. We want the story id for the current user but the like id (LID) for the user that liked the post

Comment: that's strange, it should throw you out who liked that article based on `points.LID = wp_users2.ID ` regardless is there any value in points.LID.

please see my revised answer, because i wrongly type `==` in the join.